# Камера поворачивается неправильно в Unity?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал вот такой скрипт для поворачивания камеры по движению мыши:

```html
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class TestScript0 : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Vector3 LastMousePosition;
    private Vector3 NowMousePosition;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        LastMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        NowMousePosition = Input.mousePosition;
        transform.Rotate(0, NowMousePosition.x - LastMousePosition.x, 0);
        transform.Rotate(LastMousePosition.y - NowMousePosition.y, 0 ,0);
        LastMousePosition = NowMousePosition;
    }
}
```

Когда двигаю мышь строго по вертикали или по строго горизонтали, всё нормально, но когда двигаю по вертикали и горизонтали одновременно камера поворачивается в бок.
Сам скрипт прикреплён к камере.

Comment: И ты даже не догадываешься почему? Тут всего полторы  строчки кода.

Comment: По твоему для этого нужно много кода писать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Реализация через transform.Rotate() довольно сомнительная.
Лучше это сделать через Quaternion.Euler().
Выглядит примерно так:

```
[SerializeField] private float sensetivity;

void Update()
{
    X += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * sensetivity; // Получаем X
    Y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * sensetivity; // Получаем Y
    Y = Mathf.Clamp(Y,-90f,90f); // Ограничиваем вращение по вертикали  на 90 градусов
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(-Y,X,+0f); // Применяем вращение
}
```